# How can I activate a pyvenv virtualenv from within python? (activate_this.py was removed?)

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, python-venv, virtual-environment, pyvenv

I'm using Python 3.4, and having created a pyvenv, I'm looking to activate it from within a python process. With virtualenv, I used to use `activate_this.py`, but that appears to be gone in pyvenv.

Is there now an easy way to effectively change the current interpreter to the virtualenv interpreter? I could probably mess around with the PATH (which is what `activate_this.py` did), but I'd like a simpler and stabler way.

This is for use in a wsgi.py.

Comment: Yes, the activation script depends on your platform: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Also, activating within a Python process doesn't entirely make sense. You can only activate a virtualenv and then afterwards use the Python interpreter that belongs to that virtualenv.

Comment: I think if you read here, you'll see why it makes sense: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#using-virtualenv-without-bin-python
This is the feature I'm looking for which appears to be gone in pyvenv.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. It could be a missing feature; Python 3.x isn't used much yet so it could be a legitimate missing feature.

Comment: Could be. I'll probably just end up messing with Apache's httpd.conf and try to point it at the right interpreter/python home.

Comment: @ChrisCooper the above link is broken. Which version of virtualenv? I got 12.1.0 and `activate_this.py` is there for me or I didn't get something right from your question.

Comment: "Python 3.x isn't used much yet" That is definitely not true.

Answer (score 9):

`pyvenv` and the `venv` module don't support this out of the box. The third party `virtualenv` package [does support this using `activate_this.py`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-virtualenv-without-bin-python), but [that feature was not included in the built-in `venv` module](https://bugs.python.org/issue21496).

You could try to borrow a copy of `activate_this.py` from a `virtualenv` based environment; it seems to work, though I can't swear it will be perfect (`venv`/`pyvenv` uses some magic during startup; unclear if all of it is replicated via `activate_this.py`).

The `virtualenv` docs for it are out of date for Python 3 (they claim you use `execfile`, which doesn't exist). The Python 3 compatible alternative would be:

```
activator = 'some/path/to/activate_this.py'  # Looted from virtualenv; should not require modification, since it's defined relatively
with open(activator) as f:
    exec(f.read(), {'__file__': activator})
```

Nothing `activate_this.py` does is magical, so you could manually perform the same changes without looting from `virtualenv` (adjusting `PATH`, `sys.path`, `sys.prefix`, etc.), but borrowing makes it much simpler in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I looted it from [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/activate_this.py) as [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) did not seem to have one.

Comment: The 'does support this using activate_this.py' link 404s now. I found a reference to this file in a vim script, and I was hoping to find out what it actually does. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelScheper: Sadly, it looks like the updated [user guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) no longer documents `activate_this.py` at all.

Answer (score 1):

I used a different approach used in `virtualenv` itself:

```
# the current Python interpreter is not from the virtual environment
file = __file__
if file.endswith('.pyc'):
    file = file[:-1]
venv_executable = PROJECT_DIR / 'venv' / 'bin' / 'python'
popen = subprocess.Popen([venv_executable, file] + sys.argv[1:])
raise SystemExit(popen.wait())
```

Comment: just use `sys.exit` instead of raising SystemExit

Answer (score 0):

save the following as the file activate_this.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Activate virtualenv for current interpreter:

Use exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file}).

This can be used when you must use an existing Python interpreter, not the virtualenv bin/python.
"""
import os
import site
import sys

try:
    abs_file = os.path.abspath(__file__)
except NameError:
    raise AssertionError("You must use exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file}))")

bin_dir = os.path.dirname(abs_file)
base = bin_dir[: -len("__BIN_NAME__") - 1]  # strip away the bin part from the __file__, plus the path separator

# prepend bin to PATH (this file is inside the bin directory)
os.environ["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join([bin_dir] + os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.pathsep))
os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"] = base  # virtual env is right above bin directory

# add the virtual environments libraries to the host python import mechanism
prev_length = len(sys.path)
for lib in "__LIB_FOLDERS__".split(os.pathsep):
    path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(bin_dir, lib))
    site.addsitedir(path.decode("utf-8") if "__DECODE_PATH__" else path)
sys.path[:] = sys.path[prev_length:] + sys.path[0:prev_length]

sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
sys.prefix = base
```