# Django on Apache2: Issue in.conf-file?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

Good day to all of you,

together with our admin in our company, we're trying to deploy Django on Apache2 together with mod_wsgi, but we're facing some minor issues. I'm hoping, some of you might help and take a look at the following lines!?

Right now, the directory on our server is looking like this:

```
./var/www/
        |-- myproject
            |-- manage.py
            |-- project/
                |-- __init__.py
                |-- settings.py
                |-- urls.py
                |-- wsgi.py
            |-- statics
            |-- venv
```

When I'm trying to open the site, it just keeps on loading but nothings gonna happen! I'm wondering wether the data inside our .conf-file might be wrong!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
. . .

Alias /static /var/www/myproject/static
<Directory /var/www/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/myproject/project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/var/www/myproject python-home=/var/www/myproject/venv
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/project/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

If I understood it correctly, the "**python-home**" inside the "**WSGIDaemonProcess**" should point onto my Virtual Environment to collect the necessary components and the "**python-path**" onto my project!?

```
import os 
import time 
import traceback 
import signal 
import sys 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 

sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/project')
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages') 

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings") 

try: 
    application = get_wsgi_application() 
except Exception: 
    # Error loading applications 
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules: 
        traceback.print_exc() 
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT) 
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

Does the second "**sys.get.append**" has to point to my **venv** or to the location where our admin installed the actutal python-version(**3.7**)?

I also noticed, that the current running python-version on the server is **2.7.6**, although my admin installed version **3.7**. The installed mod_wsgi is "**libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3**" for python 3x! Could this also be a problem?

Thanks and a great day to all of you!

Comment: can you show us `wsgi.py` file ?

Comment: @cizario Sorry, I forgot, added it now! And thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should activate first the virtual environment, that's why you got the default version 2.7.6 of python and not 3.7 as expected, to do so, you have to add those two lines in your `wsgi.py` file at the very top

```
activate_this = '/var/www/myproject/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
[..]
```

refer to this topic https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#daemon-mode-multiple-applications

## Note

since you've chosen `venv` over `mkviratualenv` the easiest option is to download `activate_this.py` script from `virtualenv` repository :https://github.com/dcreager/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_support/activate_this.py and put it under `venv/bin` (or `venv/Scripts` if you are on windows) since it's not shipped with (because it's not an official part of it)

for more detailed infos refer to this thread [How can I activate a pyvenv vitrualenv from within python? (activate_this.py was removed?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462582/how-can-i-activate-a-pyvenv-vitrualenv-from-within-python-activate-this-py-was)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Waiting for tomorrow to try it out! But it's interesting: no online tutorial or documentation I found mentioned this topic! Anyway...thank you!

Comment: let me know if my answer solves your issue @finethen

Comment: Sorry, almost forgot: this solution solved my problems! Thanks! @cizario